# How to use pespective CSS3 on parent/ancestor without affecting the text?

Tags: css

I have a little issue with the text when using pespective on one of the  ancestors.
Need to use perspective so I can create the desired shape. The drawback of using it is that the text gets larger on the right hand side, is not that sharp, plus its orientation is affected.

Is there a solution for this? Maybe even a different aproach how to get the same shape without affecting the text.

Many thanks for any help :)

Here is the code:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emanuela_ianc/1ct8xgLw/)

```css
.original{
    perspective: 200px;
    perspective-origin: -15% 0;
    position:absolute;
    left:4%;
    top:17%;
}
.spin{
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.slide-info {
    padding:1em;
    background-color: rgba(13,166,229,.5);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotateX(-6deg) skew(-4deg) scaleY(1.5) rotateY(-4deg) skewY(-1.5deg);
    color: #fff;
}
h4{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1.5em;
    transform: skew(4deg) scaleY(1) skewY(1.5deg);
}
p{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1em;
    transform: skew(4deg) scaleY(1) skewY(1.5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="original">
    <div class="spin">
        <div class="slide-info">
            <h4>A long long title ............... AAAAAA</h4>
            <p>Some long text in here text in here some text</p>
            <p>Some text in here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the `slide-text` from the `spin` and `position` it `absolute`

Now you can define the size of the shape by giving it `width` and `height` values.

You can change the position of the text by altering the values for `top: 0px` and `left: 0px`

```css
.original{
    perspective: 200px;
    perspective-origin: -15% 0;
    position:absolute;
    left:4%;
    top:17%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.spin{
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    background-color: rgba(13,166,229,.5);
    transform: rotateX(-6deg) skew(-4deg) scaleY(1.5) rotateY(-4deg) skewY(-1.5deg);
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
}
.slide-text {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

h4{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1.5em;
}
p{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="original">
    <div class="spin"></div>
    <div class="slide-text">
        <h4>A long long title ............... AAAAAA</h4>
        <p>Some long text in here text in here some text</p>
        <p>Some text in here</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help. I have made a small change on your code, moved -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden; on <div class="original">

Answer (score 1):

Put the background on a separate div.

```css
.original {
    perspective: 200px;
    perspective-origin: -15% 0;
    position:absolute;
    left:4%;
    top:17%;
}
.spin {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.slide-info {
    padding:1em;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.slide-info-bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(13, 166, 229, .5);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotateX(-6deg) skew(-4deg) scaleY(1.5) rotateY(-4deg) skewY(-1.5deg);
}
h4 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1.5em;
    transform: skew(4deg) scaleY(1) skewY(1.5deg);
}
p {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1em;
    transform: skew(4deg) scaleY(1) skewY(1.5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="original">
    <div class="spin">
        <div class="slide-info">
            <div class="slide-info-bg"></div>
             <h4>A long long title ............... AAAAAA</h4>

            <p>Some long text in here text in here some text</p>
            <p>Some text in here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```